# Java selenium - Maven cucumber reporting library stopped working on update from Selenium 4.13.0 to Selenium 4.14.1

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, reporting

After update to selenium 4.14.1 from selenium 4.13.0 cucumber reporting masterthought maven-cucumber-reporting stopped generating reports with a use of maven command: mvn verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@desktop. On selenium 4.13.0 everything was fine.

In target folder /jsonReport both files are empty:

```
cucumber-report.html
cucumber-report.json
```

This is test runner class

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features",
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/jsonReports/cucumber-report.json",
                "html:target/jsonReports/cucumber-report.html"},
        glue= {"stepDefs"},
        stepNotifications = true,
        monochrome = true
        )
public class TestRunner {
}
```

I am using in POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```